# React Router v4 migrate error webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-redux

I try to migrate to react-router v4 , but have some problem when run app,  **webpack_require**.i(...) is not a function, what step should I do to migrate to router v4. IS any body to met this error before. What did I mess?

Answer (score 0):

React Router v4 is splitted into [multiple modules](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v4.1.1#packages) in order to cleanly support both browsers and native apps.

Therefore starting from version 4, if you're building a web app, you should no more install `react-router` directly, but install `react-router-dom` which consists of [react router "core" plus web-related packages](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.1.1/packages/react-router-dom/package.json#L42).

I personally found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kennetpostigo/7eb7f30162253f995cd4371d85c1e196) very helpful for getting how to migrate from 3 to 4.

Comment: so I can use only react-router-dom or should install both 
 npm install --save react-router@next and  npm install --save react-router-dom@next

Comment: `react-router-dom` installs `react-router` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Install react router(v 4.0.0-alpha5) and save it to package.json from command

```
npm i react-router-next --save
```

and then import like this

```
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Link } from 'react-router-next'
```

It will work fine